# InputRange Concatenation

Tags: range, concatenation, d

Is there a higher-order range pattern that concatenates two or more `InputRanges`?

Something like

```
foreach (e; a) {
    // do stuff with e
}
foreach (e; b) {
    // do stuff with e
}
...
```

should instead be written as

```
foreach (e; someMagic(a, b, ...)) {
    // do stuff with e
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

someMagic is chain from std.range: http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#chain

Comment: if I was faster I could just have said `s/someMagic/std.range.chain/`